# How to fetch data from multiple tables in live search using ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I know that this kind of questions have been asked and answered but my problem is little bit different. I have two tables named category and enterprises. Onkeyup I want to show records from both tables,matching that string which is entered in search box. Both tables have same column name from which record is to be shown.

My HTML code is as below :-

```
<div id="search-div2">
<input type="text" id="search-box1"/>
<div id="suggesstion-box1"></div>    
</div>
```

Jquery code is :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#search-box1").keyup(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "auto/data-fetch.php",
    data:'keyword='+$(this).val(),
    beforeSend: function(){
        $("#search-box1").css("background","whitesmoke url(auto/LoaderIcon.gif) no-repeat 560px","color","#000");
    },
    success: function(data){
        $("#suggesstion-box1").show();
        $("#suggesstion-box1").html(data);
        $("#search-box1").css("background","whitesmoke");
    }
    });
});
});
```

and data-fetch.php file is :-

```
<?php
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
if(!empty($_POST["keyword"])) {
$query ="SELECT * FROM enterprises WHERE name like '"  .$_POST["keyword"]. "%' ORDER BY name";
$result = $db_handle->runQuery($query) or die(mysql_error());
if(!empty($result)) {
?>
<ul id="country-list" style="overflow-y: auto;height:210px;width:98%">
<?php
foreach($result as $country) {
?>
<li onClick="selectCountry1('<?php echo $country["name"]; ?>');"><?php echo $country["name"]; ?></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
<?php } 
else 
{?>
<ul id="country-list"> 
 <li>Sorry, no results found</li>
</ul>
<?php
}
} 
?>
```

The code above works fine when I try to get data only from enterprise table but when I try to get data from two tables it is not working. I am also posting screenshots of structure of both tables for reference.[Screenshot of category table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrPGj.png) [Screenshot of enterprises table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phv9I.png)

I have tried UNION but "The used SELECT statements have a different number of column" error is shown. Please tell me which approach should I follow?

Comment: To use a `UNION` on tables that don't have the same number of columns, you can just add a column, ie. `... UNION SELECT id, name, NULL as description FROM category ...`.

Comment: I only see one table

Comment: yes because the code here is for one table only and it works fine. But when I am trying to do the same with two tables, this query is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use union to fetch data from different table like this

```
select * FROM enterprises WHERE name like '"  .$_POST["keyword"]. "%' ORDER BY name
union
select * FROM category WHERE name like '"  .$_POST["keyword"]. "%' ORDER BY name
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use UNION for fetching data from two different tables. The Php Query is here

```
$query ="(SELECT * FROM enterprises WHERE name like '"
    .$_POST["keyword"]. "%' ORDER BY name) UNION (SELECT * FROM category WHERE name LIKE '"  
    .$_POST["keyword"]. "%' ORDER BY name)";
```